# Как сделать чтобы эти элементы нормально работали с bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

Вот код как должно работать h ttps://codepen.io/mustafich/pen/gvwbNm

И за того что на сайте стоит bootstrap выглядит коряво https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71ce1/JlcHHop0rXM.jpg
Как сделать чтобы эти элементы нормально работали с bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задай, для своих элементов, CSS свойство `box-sizing: content-box;`, так как bootstrap всем элементам задает значение свойства `border-box`

Comment: я долго пытался сделать Спасибо тебе большое !